# How do I get started with creating a database?

Tags: sql, database, azure-storage

I am developing an app, and I need a database that my app can get data from.

I know that there are a lot of solutions to this question, and I have already tried a few:

- My online solution: Hosting the data in a SQL table on Azure DB (too expensive, ~$100/month)
- My local solution: Including the data within the app itself using SQLite (data won't update automatically unless the app is updated)

The size of the data is around ~20MB. It is expected to grow at around 5MB every year.

I am building the front-end of my app on the UWP (Win10 native app) and ASP .NET (web app) platforms.

I do not know very much at all about the best ways to host data for an app, and when I researched the topic I was overwhelmed by the amount of options available to me. 
Given my situation, would it be best to store this data locally? Or online? Maybe there is a way to host it on my own computer? What is the best strategy for this situation?

Edit: 
The privacy/security of the app is not important, in fact I hope to make it as accessible as possible for others who wish to use this data.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very broad and difficult to answer in the format of this website. I would recommend googling and reading articles related to your issue just to narrow down your question a little more. Here's the full guide on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Is this a personal app? Is this an app that needs a local app, or can it be web-based? Is any of this data personal or otherwise protected data?

Comment: Shawn - This app will be distributed to the public, but it is my own personal work. I do not expect very many people to download it, it is more of a resume-builder.

The privacy of the data is not important, in fact I hope to make it as accessible to the public as possible.